# show/hide div on select option using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I built this code in order to show/hide div when an option is selected from the list but nothing happen when i click on an option.

**My HTML :**

```
<div class="row">    
    <select name="type" id="type" style="margin-left:57px; width:153px;">
        <option ame="l_letter" value="l_letter">Large Letter</option>
        <option name="parcel" value="parcel">Parcel</option>
    </select>                    
</div>

<div class="row" id="row_dim">
    <input type="text" name="length" class="dimension" placeholder="Length">
</div>
```

**My jQuery :**

```
$(function() {
$('#row_dim').hide(); 
$('#type').change(function(){
    if($('#type').val() == 'parcel') {
        $('#row_dim').show(); 
    } else {
        $('#row_dim').hide(); 
    } 
});
});
```

Comment: Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/oemf6am8/)...

Comment: Code appears fine. Have you included jQuery correctly?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kfwn84jp/1/ ?

Comment: can be simplified as https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kfwn84jp/2/

Comment: Hi Lucas, you might want to fix "ame" for "name" in the first option attribute. Also, don't use "type" as name or id, because it is a reserved word.

Comment: Make sure that the `select` element is present when the script is executed... ie it is not created dynamically

Comment: Please provide your complete page. Without more information any answers are pure guesswork and this question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery library file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">    
    <select name="type" id="type" style="margin-left:57px; width:153px;">
        <option ame="l_letter" value="l_letter">Large Letter</option>
        <option name="parcel" value="parcel">Parcel</option>
    </select>                    
</div>

<div class="row" id="row_dim">
    <input type="text" name="length" class="dimension" placeholder="Length">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9wLn265s/

Comment: If you are going to take a comment, and make it an answer, please do it correctly and at least show how to include the jQuery script properly. :)

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: In your answer... not in a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

if your code generate to dynamic than used to this  `$(document).on`  as like this

```js
$(function() {
$('#row_dim').hide(); 
$(document).on('change', '#type', function(){
    if($('#type').val() == 'parcel') {
        $('#row_dim').show(); 
    } else {
        $('#row_dim').hide(); 
    } 
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">    
    <select name="type" id="type" style="margin-left:57px; width:153px;">
        <option ame="l_letter" value="l_letter">Large Letter</option>
        <option name="parcel" value="parcel">Parcel</option>
    </select>                    
</div>

<div class="row" id="row_dim">
    <input type="text" name="length" class="dimension" placeholder="Length">
</div>
```